# Как передать данные в <select>

Tags: javascript, php, html

У меня есть такой фильтр[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно что бы первые 2 поля не сбрасывались. Вернее при применении фильтра страница обновиться и они в любом случае сбросятся. Я понимаю что данные из них нужно сохранить (они и так сохраняются в GET) и передать их в select при загрузке страницы. Но вот как передать я не знаю.

```html
            <select class="selectpicker user" title="Выберите сотрудника" name="user[]" id="users" data-live-search="true" multiple required>           </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo ' <select class="selectpicker user" title="Выберите сотрудника" name="user[]" id="users" data-live-search="true" multiple required>';
echo '<option>--</option>';
echo '<option ' . (array_key_exists('one', $_GET) ? 'selected' : '') . '>one</option>';
echo '<option>two</option>';
echo '<option>three</option>';
echo '</select>';
```